# Class defined in another plugin cannot be found by the main plugin - Eclipse Product

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I exported my plugin project as a Product and when I run the product (eclipse application), the main plugin (`org.example.framework.core`) cannot find a class defined in another plugin (`org.example.abc`) which implements an extension to an extension point provided by the main plugin. The class is one of the elements defined in the extension. However, when I run the project in Eclipse, everything runs fine!

Here is the log (`atvste.ppt.ptfwDescription.abc.decoderInfo` is a package in `org.example.abc plugin`):

`0     [Worker-2] ERROR org.example.framework.core.ptfw.codec.decode.MsgDecoderInfo  org.example.framework.core.ptfw.codec.decode.MsgDecoderInfo.createInstance(MsgDecoderInfo.java:114) : can not create class for :atvste.ppt.ptfwDescription.abc.decoderInfo.MsgDecoderInfoABC atvste.ppt.ptfwDescription.abc.decoderInfo.MsgDecoderInfoABC cannot be found by org.example.framework.core_1.0.0.201404111439
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: atvste.ppt.ptfwDescription.abc.decoderInfo.MsgDecoderInfoABC cannot be found by org.example.framework.core_1.0.0.201404111439
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.example.framework.core.ptfw.codec.decode.MsgDecoderInfo.createInstance(MsgDecoderInfo.java:104)
    at org.example.framework.core.ptfw.codec.decode.DecoderInfo.<init>(DecoderInfo.java:56)
    at org.example.framework.core.ptfw.codec.decode.DecoderInfo.createInstance(DecoderInfo.java:125)
    at org.example.framework.core.ptfw.codec.ptfwObjectsFactory.decoderInfoItf_createInstance(ptfwObjectsFactory.java:200)
    at org.example.framework.persistence.jaxb.ptfwDescriptionPersistenceJaxb.createptfwDescription(ptfwDescriptionPersistenceJaxb.java:326)
    at org.example.framework.persistence.jaxb.ptfwDescriptionPersistenceJaxb.fillptfwDescription(ptfwDescriptionPersistenceJaxb.java:247)
    at org.example.framework.persistence.jaxb.ptfwDescriptionPersistenceJaxb.createInstance(ptfwDescriptionPersistenceJaxb.java:232)
    at org.example.framework.persistence.jaxb.ptfwDescriptionPersistenceJaxb.open(ptfwDescriptionPersistenceJaxb.java:146)
    at org.example.framework.core.ptfw.codec.ptfwDescription.createInstance(ptfwDescription.java:152)
    at org.example.framework.core.ptfw.codec.command.CmdLoadptfwDescription.loadptfwDescription(CmdLoadptfwDescription.java:50)
    at org.example.framework.core.ptfw.codec.command.CmdLoadptfwDescription.execute(CmdLoadptfwDescription.java:40)
    at org.example.framework.core.runtime.JobService$2.run(JobService.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)`

**EDIT:** Function for creating instance of the class not found

```
 public static IMessageDecoderInfo createInstance(XmlgMsgDecoderInfo pMsgDecoderInfoType,
        IMessageDecoderInfo msgDecoder)
{

    String className = pMsgDecoderInfoType.getClassName();
    if(className!=null)
    {
        try
        {
            Class<?> formalArgs[] = new Class[1];
            formalArgs[0] = XmlgMsgDecoderInfo.class;
            Class<?> clazz;
            if (msgDecoder != null)
            {
                clazz = msgDecoder.getClass();
            }
            else
            {
                clazz = Class.forName( className );
            }
            Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(formalArgs);
            java.lang.Object  actualArgs[] =
            { pMsgDecoderInfoType };

            return (IMessageDecoderInfo)constructor.newInstance(actualArgs);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            String error = "can not create class for :" +className+ " " + e.getMessage();
            if (LOGGER.isEnabledFor(Level.ERROR)) {
                LOGGER.error(error, e);
            }
            throw new CreatePtfwElementRuntimeException(error, e);
        }
    }
    return new MsgDecoderInfo(pMsgDecoderInfoType);
}`
```

Comment: How is `MsgDecoderInfo.createInstance` creating the class instance?

Comment: Using Reflection...Should I provide the code?

Comment: Ok edited the question to show the function for creating the instance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the complex class loader system used by Eclipse you cannot use `Class.forName` to load a class in another plugin.

If your code is processing an extension point definition you will have the `IConfigurationElement` for the configuration element that specifies the class name. You can use

```
IConfigurationElement configElement = ....;

Object classInstance = configElement.createExecutableExtension("class attribute name");
```

where 'class attribute name' is the name of the attribute in the extension point element that specifies the class to load. The class being created must have a no argument constructor.

Alternatively you can load a class using:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");

Class<?> theClass = bundle.loadClass("class name");

... construct as usual ...
```

If you have the `IConfigurationElement` you can get the plugin id using

```
String pluginId = configElement.getContributor().getName();
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, but instead of accesing the class with the methods above, I just added in the dependencies, the package which contains the class. Isn't the same scenario?

Comment: @JohnDoe That is ok of you can add dependencies - but that is not always possible. You might want people to write their own plugins using your extension point - they can't add dependencies to your plugin.